# gadgets: Need to uninstall a gadget programmatically through code in C#

Tags: c#, windows-desktop-gadgets

Please let me know how to uninstall a gadget programmatically. Rite now i am using this command

sidebar.exe /uninstall gadget_name

but it just pop the gadget control window, do not uninstall the specified gadget.
Am I doing anything wrong with command.
Plz help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the gadget isn't currently running (it has to be closed for uninstall anyway), you can just delete the gadget's folder, usually found in `appdata%\local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\`.

The name of the folder will be `<your-gadget-name>.gadget`.  This is pretty much what sidebar.exe does when it uninstalls a gadget anyway.